# How can I enable FTP/SFTP on Google Instance VM?

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I'm trying to update WordPress, but it asks for FTP credentials.
I successfully changed the password using this command:

```
sudo passwd
```

and I entered the FTP credentials on the form but still can't update WordPress.

Answer (score 1):

Here the instruction:

-1 ssh into the instance and run the below command

```
$ sudo su

$ apt-get update

$ apt-get install vsftpd

$ echo -e "pasv_enable=Yes\npasv_max_port=10101\npasv_min_port=10100\npasv_promiscuous=YES" >> /etc/vsftpd.conf

$ systemctl restart vsftpd
```

-2 Create a firewall rule and assign it to a target tag

```
gcloud compute --project=[your-project]  firewall-rules create myftp  --direction=INGRESS --priority=1000 --network=default --action=ALLOW --rules=tcp:20,tcp:21,tcp:10101 --source-ranges=0.0.0.0/0 --target-tags=ftp
```

-3 Add the firewall tag "ftp" to the drupal instance.

$ `gcloud compute instances add-tags [vm-name]  --zone=[vm-zone]   --tags ftp`

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that you have an FTP server such as `vsftp` running on your VM. You can check by `ssh`-ing into your VM and running:

`# ps aux | grep ftp`

If there's no ftp server running, you need to configure and start it.

Also make sure that your GCP firewall settings allow FTP.

- IN: TCP 20,21,60000-65535
- OUT: TCP 20,21,60000-65535